# Query runs in 1 minute in SSMS, but fills up tempdb with pyodbc (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have quite a large query that completes in just over a minute in SSMS, but when I run the exact same query with `SQLAlchemy` (using `pyodbc`), I receive the following error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Could not allocate space for 
object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140753617092608' in database 'tempdb' 
because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded 
files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the 
filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup. (1105) 
(SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Why does the query consume more space on the tempdb when executed via `pyodbc` than if executed in SSMS and how can I solve this? Autogrowth is set on the SQL Server (not in %) and there is space available.

**EDIT 1:**

This is the query, the final result has about 25000 rows. Basically I query the latest update for each record in that `table1`.

```sql
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
    ...
FROM table1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        field1,
        field2,
        ...
        max(field3) AS maxdate 
    FROM table1
    WHERE field4 >= '20180531 17:00' AND field4 < '20180630 17:00'
    GROUP BY
        field1,
        field2,
        ...
) AS anon_1
ON field1 = anon_1.field1
    AND field2 = anon_1.field2
    ...
    AND field3 = anon_1.maxdate
WHERE field4 >= '20180531 17:00' AND field4 < '20180630 17:00'
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've "fixed" this by using `pymssql` instead of `pyodbc`. Using that module, the execution time is virtually the same as in SSMS. Obviously this doesn't answer the question why `pyodbc` busts the tempdb. The query statements executed are the same, only the parameterisation is done slightly differently. `pyodbc` uses `?` and provides the parameters at the end, while `pymssql` passes the parameters in the form `%(param)s`.

Comment: Kindly put your query to understand better for python and SQL Server guys,

Comment: The different query performance is due to different execution plans. I suggest you peruse [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dan, but as far as I can see, that website is mostly about stored procedures, isn't it? To be clear, I wrote the query in SQLAlchemy orm and ran it. After getting the error, I printed the query statement and executed that exact query in SSMS. Could the reason still be different execution plans then?

Comment: How large is the tempdb mdf file now? If it is a dev machine, you can restart SQL Server. tempdb is re-created using the configured size each time when the server starts. Then you can run the query from your code again to see whether tempdb fills up again.

Comment: The tmpdb's size is currently 84408.07 MB. Unfortunately it's not a dev machine and I have no possibility to restart the server. In any case, I have found a "solution", see the edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why there are differences between `pyodbc` and `pymssql`, however I am going to make an assumption here in that when running via `pyodbc', the values passed into the TSQL statement are parameterized, and when running in SSMS, the values are hard-coded into the TSQL statement.

If the above is correct, then one reason it executes faster in SSMS is because the optimizer knows exactly what values it needs to optimize for, so it can create an accurate query plan.  If it is parameterized, then query optimizer has to estimate/guess what the value is, and come up with a suitable query plan. Oftentimes, the guess doesn't always product the best plan, but it can be worked around by playing with statistics, indexes, or even tinkering with the query.

So you have to look at the query plans in detail for all scenarios to get a better picture why there are differences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Greg, this is also more or less what I gathered from the link that Dan posted. *it can be worked around by playing with statistics, indexes, or even tinkering with the query* if you could expand on that as to **how**, I would accept this answer.

Comment: We would have to see the query plan, table schema and indexes defined in order to advise.